# Critical points a Morse function on SO(3)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, optimization, morse-theory

Let $f_A: SO(3) \to \mathbb{R}$ and is given by $R\mapsto \frac{1}{2}|| A - R ||_F$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$, and the norm is the Frobenius norm. As indicated in [1], the gradient of $f_A$ is $\nabla f_a = A^TR - R^TA$. Suppose A = I. Then the gradient becomes
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\nabla f_a = R - R^T.
\end{equation}
I have the following questions:

1. What are the critical points of $f_A$, i.e., for what values of $R\in SO(3)$ the equation $R - R^T = 0$? Clearly, the critical points includes {I,diag(1,-1,-1),diag(-1,-1,1),diag(-1,1,-1)}. Are these the only critical points?
2. Is the set of critical points consist of isolated points. In other words, is $f_A$ a Morse function?

Reference:
[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.14166.pdf

Comment: First, you mean $n=3$ and $f_A(R) = \frac12 \|A-R\|^2$. I don't follow that formula for the gradient at all.

Comment: If $R$ is an orthogonal matrix, $R^T =R^{-1}$, so your question reduces to  asking when $R^2=I$. In three dimensions, $R$ must be a rotation about some  fixed axis, and the rotation angle must be $\pi$. There are as many such $R$ as there are axes available to select.

Comment: @TedShifrin. Yes, $n = 3$, which I updated in the question. The formula for the gradient is $A^T R - R^T A$, where the superscript "T" is the transpose.

Comment: @MathWonk. Does that mean the set of critical points are not isolated points and hence $f_A$ is not a Morse function? Or the set of critical points has exactly four points; three maximizes and one minimizer?

Comment: The first one. There's a whole submanifold (iso to $\mathbb RP^2$) of critical points

Comment: @AlexG. Thanks for your comment. Could you please clarify which one you're referring to when you say "The first one."

Comment: By the first one I mean "the set of critical points are not isolated points and hence $f_A$ is not a Morse function"

Comment: If the critical points form a two dimensional submanifold they are very much not isolated.

Comment: @AlexG.Thanks for the explanation. I need to find an example of a Morse function on $SO(3)$ such that non of the critical points are saddle points. Let $A$ by a symmetric, positive definite matrix with distinct eigenvalues, and $R \in SO(3)$. Is the function $f_A(R) = trace(A(I-R))$ a Morse function and does not have a saddle point? Does a Morse function exist on $SO(3)$ that has no saddle point?

Comment: See the proof of Lemma 2 in:
https://doi.org/10.1109/ACC.2011.5990826

Comment: @KleinFlasche. Thanks for the reference. How does Lemma 2, in the reference, guarantees that the function has no saddle point? Am I missing something?

Comment: It does not guarantee that it has no saddle point, but that was not your question. You can use the computations there to find the critical points for your function.